# hitTestObject to a specific instance within an array. AS3 OOP

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm making a tile based game in AS3. Now I need to check a collision between the player and each tile (which are created in an array with 300-something instances). 
I want to do that in my Main class. The player is in a class called Level and the tileArray is in another class. 
When I execute, I get the classic #2007 error - "Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null".

MAIN

```
public function checkCollision():void{


        if(_level._tileSetBMP._tileArray[0] == null){
            _level._tileSetBMP._tileArray[0] as flash.display.DisplayObject; 
        }
        for (var i:int = 0; i < _level._tileSetBMP._tileList.length; i++){
            if (_player._sneezy.hitTestObject(_level._tileSetBMP._tileList[_level._tileSetBMP._tileArray[0]])) {
                trace("Die");
            }
        }       
    }
```

TILESET

```
package GameObjects{


public class TileSet extends GameObjects.GameObjects
{
    public  var _til:Tile;
    public  var _tileArray:Array = new Array;


    public function TileSet()
    {           
        _tileArray =
            [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];

        setup();

        }

    public function setup():void{

        for(var row:int = 0; row<_tileArray.length; row++)
        {
            for(var col:int = 0; col < _tileArray[row].length; col++){
                trace('type:',_tileArray[row][col]);

                if(_tileArray[row][col] == 1){
                    var tile:Tile;
                    tile = new Tile();
                    tile.x = col * (tile.width -3) + Settings.STARTX;
                    tile.y = row * (tile.height -3) + Settings.STARTY;

                    addChild(tile);
                }   

                if (_tileArray[row][col] == 0) {
                    var grassTile:Tile;
                    grassTile = new Tile();
                    grassTile.alpha = 0.1;
                    grassTile.x = col * (grassTile.width -3) + Settings.STARTX;
                    grassTile.y = row * (grassTile.height -3) + Settings.STARTY;

                    addChild(grassTile);
                }                       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to make a hitTest with each of the [0]-instances of the array?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now all you are doing is looking at the tileArray and creating the appropriate tile but when it comes time to doing a hitTest you're still looking at the tileArray which just contains numbers - obviously you can't do a hitTest between a DisplayObject and a number (and you can't just cast it into a DisplayObject as you try).

There are a couple of ways of going about it but the basic point is to push each tile into a separate array when you create it. So something like this:

```
var realTileArray:Array = [];
//...
var tile:Tile;
tile = new Tile();
tile.x = col * (tile.width -3) + Settings.STARTX;
tile.y = row * (tile.height -3) + Settings.STARTY;
addChild(tile);
realTileArray.push(tile);
```

And then for the collision test:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < realTileArray.length; i++){
    if (_player._sneezy.hitTestObject(realTileArray[i])) {
          trace("Die");
    }
}
```

Adjust as needed, but the important thing is to have two arrays - one for tile creation and one for storing actual tiles.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot! I've been wrapping my head around this for a while now. Worked like a charm! :)